# RethinkDB filter then distinct by index

Tags: filter, distinct, rethinkdb

I have a large table that grows rapidly. I want to filter by a field then get the distinct values by another field. However in RethinkDB, this causes all records to be read from disk as I see from dashboard, which takes too much time. My query is as follows:

```
r.db("mydb").table("mytable").filter({"AssetID": "a"}).pluck("StartedOn").distinct()
```

The original query was follows but RethinkDB gives an error that it is not a table.

```
r.db("mydb").table("mytable").filter({"AssetID": "a"}).distinct({index:"StartedOn"})
e: Can only perform an indexed distinct on a TABLE in:
```

Both fields StartedOn and AssetID are indexed. `filter` does not use index, so I tried to use `getAll` but still same error:

```
r.db("mydb").table("mytable").getAll("a", {index: 'AssetID'}).distinct({index:"StartedOn"})
e: Can only perform an indexed distinct on a TABLE in:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't `getAll` by one index and then use an indexed `distinct` on another index.  I would recommend an unindexed `distinct` after a `getAll` in this case.